# How to get Devstack Juno

Tags: openstack, devstack, openstack-horizon, openstack-juno

I setup Devstack using this link: http://docs.openstack.org/developer/d... . but I got openstack old version. I want Openstack Juno version in devstack. what to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found this:

## git clone https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack.git -b stable/juno

Answer (score 1):

While using Devstack, when you clone the repo from Git it will pull the latest version of Openstack only, that is the beauty of Devstack.

git clone https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack.git

We can either specify the version when cloning the repo

git clone https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack.git -b stable/juno

Answer (score 0):

Try this blog post

http://blog.phymata.com/2014/04/18/devstack-icehouse-on-the-rackspace-cloud/

But replace the word icehouse with juno everywhere.

Comment: with icehouse it works with juno it fails, seems to be images are not yet published for this.